# Disabling a material design button for a specific time between clicks in a vuejs project

Tags: javascript, button, vue.js, ecmascript-6, material-design-lite

## Question

How can I set a timeout between clicks which will toggle the disabled attribute in a button?

[image]

Due to API restrictions, queries are limited. So to prevent users from just sitting there clicking too fast and not seeing the page refresh, I want to force a time between clicks. The proposed solution that I have is to pass in the `disabled` attribute to the button after it is clicked, then remove that in 5 seconds to allow the user to click again.

### Code

Working demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM)

#### HTML

```
<button 
  v-on:click="GetTacos" 
  class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent"
  id="tacoBtn"
>new recipe</button>
```

#### JS - Babel

I originally thought that while it is disabled the following class should be removed `mdl-button--accent`. But when experimenting with the code, if you simply pass in the `disabled` attribute, the button changes style too.

[image]

---

### Background

I have found other solutions but they libraries like jQuery

- [jquery disable a button for a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649848/jquery-disable-a-button-for-a-specific-time)
- [How do I measure the time between 2 clicks of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204050/how-do-i-measure-the-time-between-2-clicks-of-a-button)

Those will not work for my specific use

I also looked at passing in disabled attribute but most of those solutions were for reactjs

- [Dynamic attribute in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103096/dynamic-attribute-in-reactjs)

Not sure how to translate those solutions to my project though.

Comment: why you can not use `setTimeout` function after request finished? something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBarJr

Comment: @MaxSinev that approach definitely works. but nothing is refreshing, so i guess i found another issue :/

Comment: what do you mean when said "nothing is refreshing"? if you want also to prevent API requests on page reload then current state should be saved to `localStorage`.

Comment: I would not recommend using Material Design Lite for a new project, due to it being in [limited support](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite#limited-support) mode. If you already have an existing project, that's different of course.